# How to simplify matching network LC circuit

Tags: rf, antenna, passive-networks, impedance-matching

I'm relatively new to RF design, and trying to implement a [Micrel reference PCB antenna design (Heli-2)](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AN52-APID.pdf). I am using a [MICRF113 RF](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/MICRF113) transmitter at **315MHz** to transmit digital data using ASK (OOK).

Here is the **50 ohm** LC matching network for the transmitter:

[image]

With the PCB antenna reference design stating an (unmatched) impedance of **11.2 – j216.1** at **315MHz**, the suggested 50 ohm matching network is:

[image]

Which I can improve by changing the inductor from 75nH to 72nH:

[image]

And improve further by re-arranging a little:

[image]

I like the third option, as it has the lowest return loss, it's not as sensitive to component/PCB tolerances, and it conveniently places a 1.8pF cap in parallel with C7 8.2pF cap on the transmitter matching network (I can replace both with a single 10pF cap).

Okay, now to the part I'm less sure about; **how can I simplify the design to use less components** while still matching impedance to keep return loss as low as possible (ideally close to an SWR of 1)? What is the math formula to simplify the design by removing/combining components?

For proof of concept, I will probably build a transmitter with all the components (matched 50 ohms in the center), so I can prove the antenna is indeed tuned to 50 ohms using a VNA. For 50 ohm transmitter matching, I will take Micrel at their word, and use the recommended components.

If I were to test the transmitter output to confirm it's matched correctly (theory isn't usually reality due to tolerances etc.), what equipment should I use? A high-speed oscilloscope? An SWR meter?

Not really relevant to the above, but for now, R7 will be a 0 ohm resistor for maximum transmit power, but can be changed to a higher resistance to reduce transmit power as described in the MICRF113 datasheet.

I would appreciate any insight into the design and optimization.

Comment: Perhaps you should try this https://www.will-kelsey.com/smith_chart/

Comment: I've used Smith charts to create matching networks, but I'm not sure how I can use it to eliminate/combine matching components.